# How can I get the default value of a column for an empty table in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, default-value

I've got a table with two columns.

```
+-------------+---------------+
|    User     |    Active     |
+-------------+---------------+
|    Geoff    |       1       |
|    Bob      |       1       |
+-------------+---------------+
```

The Active column is a `tinyint` with a default value of 0. However sometimes the default value gets set to 1, so that all future users are automatically set as active.

I can *set* the default value using this query:

```
ALTER TABLE `Users` MODIFY COLUMN `Active` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1';
```

I now need to write a query to *detect* what the default value of the column is.

Is this possible?

**Edit: I should have specified. I would like the query to *only* show the default value, since I am going to use it in some code.**

Comment: I'm not clear what you are asking here are you expecting the alter statement to fixup all the existing rows to 1?

Comment: @P.Salmon No, I just want to detect the default value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SHOW COLUMNS FROM dbname.tablename;
```

**Output**

```
Field       Type            Null        Key     Default     Extra
col1        int(10)         NO          PRI                 auto_increment      
col2        smallint(10)    YES                 0
```

Here, in the default column show if any default value is set or not

Comment: In the end I did this `SHOW COLUMNS FROM finance_org_settings WHERE Field='Active'`. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

```
SHOW CREATE TABLE Users
```

Will show you more than just that.

You can also query the `information_schema`

```
select c.COLUMN_DEFAULT
from information_schema.`COLUMNS` c
where c.TABLE_SCHEMA = 'MyDatabaseName'
  and c.TABLE_NAME = 'Users'
  and c.COLUMN_NAME = 'Active';
```

Comment: Is there a way to only fetch that value?

Answer (score 0):

Type `SHOW CREATE TABLE Users` and you'll see an output of creation of table with default value for columns.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

Check INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS table, column COLUMN_DEFAULT . More info - dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/columns-table.html